# Angular 6.x Meta Tags OG:Description not working with FB

Tags: angular, facebook, angular-universal, prerender

I have an Angular 6.x app and I am changing the Meta tags in my component using the  Meta Service. My goal was to make each route have a different image and description so they will render the preview in facebook correctly. I verified that the meta tags are actually changing, but FB does not see them. I used the FB https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ to verify my site and it work correctly if I put the meta tags in my index.html, but when I use the Meta service in the component,it does not see them. Can I assume it is because of the nature of a Single Page App? And FB is not seeing the change in metatag and I would have to pre-render them somehow with Angular Universal?  Due to the server not serving them? I am confused about Angular Universal, it seems like using that is defeating the point of the client rendering the page, and I should use something beside Angular. Would prerender.io also solve this issue for me?

Comment: Yes, the Facebook scraper doesn’t care for any client-side JavaScript. The server must return the correct meta tags directly for the requested URL. And yes, prerender.io is one of the services that can help fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. I hope in the future there is a more seamless way to do this.  If you make this an answer I will mark as the answer I accepted.. thanks

Comment: Hey @Maccurt, If u got the solution, please post here

Comment: I looked into prerender.io. https://prerender.io/

Answer (score 1):

I use @ngx-meta for universal and OG tags - and all work fine.

[FB verify](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fssr.angular.su)

[github sample](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter)

Comment: My confusion is I though there was some great benefit of having Angular render on the client, moving it to universal seems like going backwards.. I will have to look into it.. I wish the googles and fb of the world would solve this issue on their end. I probably don't understand the nature of it all to say that..